# How does GetProcAddress work

Tags: winapi, api, dll, getprocaddress

I've done some googling but haven't really found much. How does GetProcAddress work? What goes  on behind the scenes? Do the method names and their corresponding address get stored in meta data somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly. They are stored in DLL/EXE export header. You can see it with dumpbin.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Matt Pietrek's stuff on PE file format or his book *Windows 95 System Programming Secrets*. There are bounchs of custom implementatios of GetProcAddress to look in to it.